# After a time, Safari and a few other apps, can no longer connect to websites

Tags: macos, network, safari, monterey

I have a very odd issue happening on my Macbook (13-inch m1, osx 12.5.1)

After a reboot I am able to successfully use safari to navigate to any website. However after a few days of uptime the following happens:

1. The weather widget (and stocks and screentime) in the right side slidey panel w/ notifications is blank.
2. Tweetbot refuses to fetch new tweets or load any images.
3. Safari refuses to connect to any site but google (even apple.com) with an error "Safari can't open the page "" because Safari can't connect to the server "".
4. In the console there are a number of errors that seem suspicious but I'm unable to drive them to a resolution:

```
error   09:15:44.328247-0700    kernel  netagent_client_message_with_params: Send message 10 for client (error 49)
error   09:15:44.328263-0700    kernel  necp_client_add_flow: netagent_client_message error (49)
error   09:15:44.328274-0700    kernel  necp_client_add_flow: Add flow error (49)
error   09:15:44.332999-0700    kernel  netagent_client_message_with_params: Send message 10 for client (error 49)
error   09:15:44.333007-0700    kernel  necp_client_add_flow: netagent_client_message error (49)
error   09:15:44.333023-0700    nsurlsessiond   nw_path_evaluator_create_flow_inner NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_ADD_FLOW BBFFF3E3-6789-4BBA-96DC-A389F983C687 [49: Can't assign requested address]
error   09:15:44.333014-0700    kernel  necp_client_add_flow: Add flow error (49)
...
error   09:15:44.362855-0700    nsurlsessiond   nw_path_evaluator_create_flow_inner NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_ADD_FLOW 5927CE5A-0A2C-441A-8C4C-F64E310435B8 [49: Can't assign requested address]
error   09:15:44.362946-0700    nsurlsessiond   nw_endpoint_flow_setup_channel [C1337.1.8 IPv4#cdc52b8f:443 in_progress channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] failed to request add nexus flow
...
error   09:15:46.129189-0700    Safari  0x12bb8e018 - [pageProxyID=529, webPageID=530, PID=63305] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=23, isMainFrame=1, domain=<private>, code=-1004, isMainFrame=1
error   09:15:46.129306-0700    Safari  Web view (pid: 63305) did fail provisional navigation (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "(null)")
error   09:15:46.129354-0700    Safari  Displaying webpage loading error to user: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "(null)", networkTaskDescription: LocalDataTask <3912D374-3D7C-4298-B46D-CCBAAEFD1D50>.<242>.
```

5. I am still able to use curl and firefox without issue  to browse the web. (I even have tried exiting firefox and restarting it to see if that causes it to hang as well. Works fine)
6. Slack continues to function normally.

Some potentially complicating or related factors:

1. I do run little snitch, however the following happens with the filter on or off. I get no alerts when the filter is on.
2. I have no proxy settings defined in the network control panel for my wifi connection.
3. I have tried to resolve this by force-quitting various processes such as nsurlsessiond, mdnsresponder and it's helper. Fruitless, only a reboot fixes it.
4. I have done some dumps of `sudo netstat -s > nsdashs-brokenagain` both before and after failures just to see if i notice any patterns, nothing yet. (socket exhaustion? filehandle exhaustion etc..?)

edit, here are some more logs: https://gist.github.com/SleepyBrett/1f9f0db4f902994bfa94fcd8eb5ae992

Comment: I am no expert whatsoever but I think that Firefox doesn't use Apples WebKit while Safari and presumably TweetBot and the weather widget use it

Comment: Yes this is my diagnosis as well. Though the anomaly of being able to hit google.com (and do searches) is very confusing.

Comment: @BrettWagner Have you tried reinstalling macOS and upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: @RusticChevalier honestly a reinstall seems like a huge pain in the ass, and i'm already on latest.

Comment: I think I have traced this back to either macos or pathfinder having mounted smb shares that contain lots of files (directories with 2k-5k files in them). Usually with my normal workflow I have a few shared network drives attached all day and I leave them that way. Within 48-72 hours the issue presents. I'm now on day 10 without mounting a drive and no problems yet.